# What is the covariant form of the gamma matrix?

Tags: matrices

The [Dirac gamma matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) is defined as:
$$ \gamma^0 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

I came across a $\gamma_0$, but am unfamiliar with the "covariant form" of matrices. What do the component entries for $\gamma_0$ actually look like?

Comment: The wikipedia article you linked has a clear and direct explanation of the covariant matrices in the second sentence of the first section. Is there something about the procedure to numerically compute the contraction that you have a question about?

Comment: @NinadMunshi thank you. The Wiki article uses very dense notation, and I am completely unfamiliar with contravariant and covariant terminology. I suppose the $\gamma_0$ is related to $\gamma^0$ by a simple relation, like changing the signs of certain entries?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Mathematical_structure Could you read this section and tell me what level of background you're familiar with? That way I can better understand how to formulate a useful answer for you. Do you know how to contract tensors or use Einstein summation?

Comment: @NinadMunshi thank you. I am vaguely familiar with the technical definitions of contract tensors, but for the present I only need to calculate in passing $\gamma^0\gamma_0$ = ? in matrix form, so I was hoping that an explicit 4x4 matrix entries answer of what $\gamma_0$ looks like will be sufficient for my immediate calculations.